# SQL Services are off but can access and query from other server on the same domain. Why?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, sql-server-2019

Using configuration manager, I disabled the SQL Server Services for a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance. Yet, I can still connect to the instance from its replacement server, a SQL 2019 box, and query the data! Also, the jobs which I disabled are enabled and appear to have been running. Locally, I cannot connect. I'd like to understand why this is occurring.

**Follow-up**: There was an alias named after the old 2008 instance. When you connected using that alias on the new machine, it would connect you to the new sql instance. Hence the confusion.

Comment: please add more details (I'm confuse by you "replacement server"). You stopped service on Server A and you can access the DB on server B ??

Comment: The replacement server is the SQL Server 2019 instance and it is replacing the 2008 R2 instance. 2008 is no longer supported. A side-by-side upgrade was done and now it is time to shut down the 2008R2 instance. Services were stopped on the 2008R2 instance but I can still access that instance from the 2019 box.

Comment: How do you *know* it's that instance? Did you `SELECT @@SERVERNAME, @@VERSION;`? It's quite likely you're getting routed there by DNS or host files or an alias that was set up to make the migration more seamless.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Bingo. I think that's it. Event though I specify server A when I connect via SSMS, it is really Server B.

Answer (score 3):

There are two options:

a) The service isn't stopped.

b) You access some *other* SQL server instance from your 2019 machine.

It is literally impossible to access a SQL server which isn't running, so we can rule that out.

My guess is that you have a client alias on the 2019 machine with the name of the old 2008 machine (and possibly instance), which points back to the 2019 machine (and possibly instance). You find these in SQL Server Configuration Manager under "SQL Native Client xx Configuration". Make sure you check out both the 64 and 32 bit entries!